# Yii selgridview doesn't seem to hold my selected values

Tags: javascript, checkbox, yii, frameworks, yii-extensions

I am using Yii 1.x with the selgridview extension which simply remembers selected rows when sorting or paging. The demo here demonstrates exactly what this does - http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/selgridview/

I have followed the instructions and while it does work, it doesn't work 100% as per the demo above.
I have a grid which has 21 rows which spans over 3 pages in the pager (e.g 10 rows per page).

When I attempt to select an checkbox & then go to another page in the pager and then go back to the initial checkbox it is no longer checked.

For instance if I select checkbox '4' on page 1, then navigate to the 3 page in the pager and then return back to page 1 the checkbox 4 is no longer checked (even though I just checked this). I have the 'checked' parameter in the widget pulling in an array of pre-selected checkboxes. This is just a standard array e.g Array ( [0] => 5454 [1](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/selgridview) => 11402 [2] => 11481 )

This will simply pre-select a number of checkboxes on page load (this element works fine), I cannot understand why when I check a checkbox and navigate to another page of the grid recordset it loses the selection I have just made.

Could anyone provide any advice?

Extension for remembering the selected options in gridview,check this link [Selgridview](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/selgridview)

// form view below

```
        <div class="controls">
        <?php $this->widget('ext.selgridview.BootSelGridView',array(
            'id'            => 'teachers-grid',
            'type'          => 'striped bordered condensed',
            'dataProvider' => new CArrayDataProvider($model->getAvailableTeachers(), array(
               'keyField' => 'user_id'
            )),
            'selectableRows' => true,
            'columns' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'user_id',
                    'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
                    'checked' => 'in_array($data->user_id, $this->grid->owner->model->teacher_ids)',
                    'checkBoxHtmlOptions' => array(
                        'name' => get_class($model)."[teachers][]"
                    )
                ),
                'user_id',
                'email',
            )
        )); ?>
    </div>
```

P.S I am using 'path' as my urlFormat parameter in my Yii config